# I am trying to add products to database using mysqli and php but nothing gets added

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a page to add inventory to a database using mysqli and php. When I fill out the information and hit the submit button, nothing happens. the fields just go blank. I check the database and nothing is put in.

Can someone help me figure where the error is?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include_once("../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");

if(isset($_POST['button'])) {

$item_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['item_number']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
$qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['qty']);

// See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = ("SELECT id FROM products WHERE item_number='$item_number' LIMIT 1");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $productMatch = mysqli_num_rows($result); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "item_number" into the system, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    //Add to inventory now

$sql = "INSERT INTO products ('item_number', 'price', 'category', 'description', 'qty', 'date_added')
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "sql error";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $item_number, $desc, $price, $catagory, $qty, now());

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
    $pid = mysqli_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.png";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../pictures/inventory/$newname");
}
}
?>
<?php
$product_list = '';
include_once("../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$product_count = mysqli_num_rows( $result);
if ($product_count > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $item_number = $row["item_number"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
             $qty = $row["qty"];
    } 
} else {
        $product_list = "You Have No Items In Inventory";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="samuel jaycox">
<title>Inventory List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="pictures/pinky.png">
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <div id="pageContent"><br />
    <div align="right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New Inventory Item </a></div>
<div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>Inventory list</h2>
      <?php echo $product_list; ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a name="inventoryForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
    <h3>
    &darr; Add New Inventory Item Form &darr;
    </h3>
    <form action="inventory_list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST">
    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Item Number</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="item_number" type="text" id="item_number" size="64" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Price</td>
        <td><label>
          $
          <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Category</td>
        <td><label>
          <select name="category" id="category">
          <option value="Bracelets">Bracelet</option>
          <option value="Necklace">Necklace</option>
          <option value="Earring">Earring</option>
          <option value="Childrens">Childrens</option>
          <option value="Sets">Sets</option>
          <option value="Rosary">Rosary</option>
          <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Description</td>
        <td><label>
          <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="64" rows="20"></textarea>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Qty</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="qty" type="text" id="qty" size="9" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Image</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <br />
  <br />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new at mysqli and just do not know where to begin looking. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: You might want to look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php on how to use prepared statements. Notice these `?` characters in the queries, these are the important things.

Comment: I didn't get any error messages. the fields ust go back to being blank.

Comment: Try removing the single quote from the entity name. Use this sql `$sql = "INSERT INTO products (item_number, price, category, description, qty, date_added)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";` @SamuelJaycox

Comment: You won't need mysqli escaping if you are using prepared statements throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code at the top of your php code :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // add this too
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will show all error that will help you and also, add this code too after your `mysql_stmt_execute()` :

```
echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
```

This code will return mysql error message that may help. Don't forget to paste the error message to your question.

EDIT : About your code,
if I am correct, you are trying to use prepared statements. it should be

```
//add ? marker, see official php page about prepared statements
$sql = "INSERT INTO products ('item_number', 'description', 'price', 
'catagory', 'qty', 'date_added')
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "sql error";
} else {
    //parameters (variable) are binded here. s for string, see official php page for more information. 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $item_number, $desc, $price, $catagory, $qty, now());

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $pid = mysqli_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.png";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], 
"../pictures/inventory/$newname");
}
    header("location: inventory_list.php?item addes successfully");
}
```

see [mysqli bind param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

EDIT 2 :
try adding this code after `$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");` to check your connection.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

And also remove ' (apostrophe) from `$sql = "INSERT INTO products ('item_number', 'price', 'category', 'description', 'qty', 'date_added') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";`

EDIT 3 :
There is no `now()` function in php, you can either change it into `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` or change your prepared statements code into the following.

```
//now() function is mysql function, so it should be called in sql query.
$sql = "INSERT INTO products ('item_number', 'description', 'price', 
'catagory', 'qty', 'date_added')
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "sql error";
} else {
    //remove now() function.
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $item_number, $desc, $price, $catagory, $qty);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $pid = mysqli_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.png";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], 
"../pictures/inventory/$newname");
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and still nothing happens. I got no error messages. Could there be a problem with the database itself and it's not allowing the item to be added?

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : Which changes? Displaying errors (top) or the Prepared statements (below)? Did you add it inside the `<?php` tag?

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : I just added a new line to show error, please insert that line too inside `<?php` tag

Comment: I added all lines inside the <?php tag. When I add the information into the fields and hit the submit button nothing happens. I refresh the database and nothing shows up as being put into the database. I get no error messages either when I run the code. I cannot figure this out.

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : From what I see, it's because you added `header("location: inventory_list.php?item addes successfully");` line which redirect you to a new page with no error. Try removing that line for debugging purpose and try submitting again.

Comment: Took out the line and ran it again. I got the sql error message. I looked over the code and I noticed that some of the functions like mysqli_stmt_init() are in blue while others like mysqli_stmt_bind_param() are in white (like plain text). I am using dreamweaver cc to write the code. could this be the reason for the sql error?

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : lol, can you edit your question and add the SQL error message, and your current code too?

Comment: My new code is at the top of the page. I just edited it there.

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : please paste the sql error message here too.

Comment: All it says is sql error. There is nothing else. And the fields go back to being empty.

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : I get it, see my answers again (EDIT 2).

Comment: Now received an error:  Connection opened
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function now() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pinkys_pearls\storeadmin\inventory_list.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pinkys_pearls\storeadmin\inventory_list.php on line 37

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : because there is no `now()` function in php. Change it into `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` or see my EDIT 3 answer.

Comment: Thank you Howard Lie! I did as you suggested and I can now add inventory to my database.

Comment: @SamuelJaycox : You can accept my answer (the tick besides my answer) if it fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your value part of your query is wrong. Should be Values(‘value1’, and so on) 
In your case  it is just values(value1, and that’s not the correct way.

You can always echo your Sql statement and run the query in a Sql client like HeidiSQL or the CLI for MySQL.